# UIPresentationController -- animate alongside Interactive Transition?

Tags: ios

I've created a UIPresentationController that adds a simple `tintAdjustmentView` to the PresentationController's `containerView` like so:

```
- (void)presentationTransitionWillBegin {

UIView* containerView = [self containerView];
[containerView insertSubview:self.tintAdjustmentView atIndex:0];
self.tintAdjustmentView.frame = containerView.bounds;
self.tintAdjustmentView.alpha = 0.f;

id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> coordinator = [[self presentedViewController] transitionCoordinator];
if (coordinator) {
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>context) {
        [self.tintAdjustmentView setAlpha:1.0];
    } completion:nil];
} else {
    [self.tintAdjustmentView setAlpha:1.0];
}
}
```

When I use a basic `<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>` object, this works as desired -- the adjustment view updates the alpha while animated.

Now, I've also started using a custom `<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>` object to power an interactive transition. Note this is not a `UIPercentDrivenInteractionTransition` object.

Unfortunately, the `tintAdjustmentView` does not animate when I use the interactive transition. How can I animate the view along with the interactive transition?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm trying to avoid using `UIPercentDrivenInteractionTransition`, and have the same issue--animation block finishes instantly.

Comment: Same. Did something come of this?